# I want to play with a dynamic class in vue js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I want to play with a dynamic class that will hide the component when the height is x or less, how can I force vue js to refresh the class, this is my code

```
    <template>
    <Tablet :class="[view ?'show-div' : 'hiden-div']"></Tablet>
</template>
<script>
import Tablet from '../components/tablet/tablet';

export default {
    name:'inicio',
    components:{
        Tablet
    },
    data(){
        return{
            view:true
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        screen.orientation.addEventListener('change',function(){
            if(screen.orientation.type == 'landscape-primary'){
               if(screen.height <= 630){
                   console.log(screen.height+ 'es menor de')
                   this.view=false;
               }
            }
        });        
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Looks ok to me. Is it not working? You may want to add an `else { this.view = true }` after your `if` otherwise it will never change back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably can use resize event listener or try with orientation change. So you can change your `this.view` when there is a browser/window size change.

```js
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(event) {
  console.log("the orientation of the device is now " + event.target.screen.orientation.angle);
});

window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
    console.log(document.body.clientWidth + ' wide by ' + document.body.clientHeight+' high');
})
```

to use it in Vuejs

```
mounted () {
  window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
    console.log(document.body.clientWidth + ' wide by ' +     document.body.clientHeight+' high');
    // listen changes
    if (document.body.clientWidth < some value) {
     this.view = true
    }
  })
}
```